Reference of incident where the sahaba were to pray Asr after reaching their destination?
There is a hadees about sahaba when they set on a journey prophet (SAA) said that pray asar’s prayer at some destination but the time of prayer come during the journey so some sabaha pray asar prayer while some pray when they reach the destination


قال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم لنا لما رجع من الأحزاب ‏ "‏ لا يصلين أحد العصر إلا في بني قريظة ‏"‏‏.‏ فأدرك بعضهم العصر في الطريق فقال بعضهم لا نصلي حتى نأتيها، وقال بعضهم بل نصلي لم يرد منا ذلك‏.‏ فذكر للنبي صلى الله عليه وسلم فلم يعنف واحدا منهم‏‏
When the Prophet (ﷺ) returned from the battle of Al-Ahzab (The confederates), he said to us, "None should offer the 'Asr prayer but at Bani Quraiza." The 'Asr prayer became due for some of them on the way. Some of them decided not to offer the Salat but at Bani Quraiza while others decided to offer the Salat on the spot and said that the intention of the Prophet (ﷺ) was not what the former party had understood. And when that was told to the Prophet (ﷺ) he did not blame anyone of them.
— Bukhari

